# Apple powerbook G4 17" Trying to install Linux

Tags: install, startup, unix, powerbook

I believe followed the directions on how to create a bootable USB drive from the Ubuntu website. My question is how can I get my Powerbook to boot from the USB drive? I tried doing the command+control+o+f and it just shows me the file icon with the question mark I also tried booting it holding the option button and it directs me to a screen with two buttons a refresh and a next button, I click on the next button and nothing happens?? kinda stumped.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the Powerbooks don't boot from USB drives. You'll need to burn a CD.

I'm going to assume that you downloaded Ubuntu from the homepage at Ubuntu.com, which will give you ISOs for Intel (x86 and x64) processors. Since your computer has a PowerPC processor, you will need to download that ISO: [Ubuntu's wiki for installing on PowerPC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC)

**Edit** - [Someone on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6705880&postcount=5) says you should be sure to download the livecd version and set arguments for loading the kernel:

> Be sure to down load the powerpc live disk. 8.04.1 will give you the least trouble with booting. On my Ibook I have to press the tab key as the first words come up as it begins to boot. This takes you to a screen with some options to load the kernel. The one that works for me is "linux-nosplash-powerpc".

Comment: Thanks for that info beats having to keep trying something that doesn't work. What if my ROM drive is bad? Could I load it off an external ROM drive? The laptop will boot in open firmware??

Comment: @EstelaSanchez This (otherwise irrelevant) [article](http://lifedigital2010.wordpress.com/2011/04/03/how-to-install-mac-osx-from-usb-on-powerbook-g4/) says that it can boot from a CD drive connected over FireWire. Haven't found anything about USB.